# Не понимаю как через такой скрипт передать информацию об уроне в другой скрипт

Tags: unity3d

Вот скрипт выстрела

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _gunDammage;
    [SerializeField] private float _fireDistance;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject player;

    private bool _haveHoot;
    private RaycastHit hitData;

    private void Update()
    {
        FireRay();      
        GunShoot();
    }

    private void GunShoot()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (hitData.transform.tag == TagEnum.Enemy.ToString() && _haveHoot)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void FireRay()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));
        Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitData);
  
        float x = hitData.transform.position.x - player.transform.position.x;
        float y = hitData.transform.position.y - player.transform.position.y;

        if (x <= _fireDistance && y <= _fireDistance)
            _haveHoot = true;
        else
            _haveHoot = false;
    }
}
```

Вот скрип который должен принимать этот урон

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHealt : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _enemyHealth;

    private void Update()
    {      
        if(_enemyHealth <= 0)
        {
            _enemyHealth = 0;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Так, вот решение всем спасибо

```
    private void GunShoot()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            FireRay();
            if (hitData.transform.tag == TagEnum.Enemy.ToString() && _haveHoot)
            {
                hitData.transform.GetComponent<EnemyHealt>().ApplyDamage(_gunDammage);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public void ApplyDamage(float damage)
    {
        _enemyHealth -= damage;
    }

    private void Update()
    {      
        if(_enemyHealth <= 0)
        {
            _enemyHealth = 0;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```